# Why Ubuntu got freezes unexpectedly?

Tags: shutdown, hardware, crash, reboot

I have installed fresh **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** as a primary os. After running it, It got freezes several times and even the mouse crusor doesn't respond and sometimes it got reboot and sometimes I have to press power button to shut it down. It doesn't respond until I manually shut it down and start my pc again and Here's my PC specification

- **Memory - 2GB**
- **Processor - Intel® Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz * 2**
- **Graphics -Intel® HD Graphics 2000 (SMB GT1)**
- **Disk capacity - 500GB**

I am using ubuntu latest version It even get freeze while I am not using any program. So, is it some pc hardaware issue or what ?

Comment: It is most likely because the memory is getting consumed, and system is switching to swap, which is slow. Increasing swap may not help much because swap is much slower than physical RAM. Use Lubuntu instead. It consumes less memory https://lubuntu.me/.

Comment: It's probably a combination of insufficient RAM and running in a slow HDD.

Comment: Bare min hardware never a good idea.

Comment: I agree with @ArchismanPanigrahi  I'd check what swap you have enabled; and for sure consider running a *lighter* desktop.  I QA-test various systems (esp. Lubuntu) on different hardware but rarely use a laptop with 2GB for main Ubuntu as it makes no sense as the minimum required ram is 4GB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) so problems should have been expected in your case given you've not got the minimum specs for your installed OS. Lubuntu is not your only choice; the *best* choice depends on what apps you'll run; but Lubuntu is the *lightest* out-of-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "nolapic" boot parameter did the trick  but it disables my one cpu core so perfomance seems to be decreased.

Comment: Additional information may be needed to make this answer robust.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ArchismanPanigrahi.  I'd check what swap you have enabled; and for sure consider running a *lighter* desktop.

I QA-test various systems (esp. Lubuntu) on different hardware but rarely use a laptop with 2GB for main Ubuntu as it makes no sense as the minimum required isn't met, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements lists requirements as

> **Ubuntu Desktop Edition**
>
> - 2 GHz dual core processor
> - **4 GiB RAM (system memory)**
> - 25 GB (5 GB for minimal) of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative    approach)
> - VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
> - Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
> - Internet access is helpful

so problems should have been expected in your case given you've not got the minimum specs for your installed OS.

Lubuntu is not your only choice; the *best* choice depends on what apps you'll run (eg. if you want to use GTK3 apps I'd most likely use Xubuntu instead); but Lubuntu is the *lightest* out-of-box.